# What's the most resource efficient way to count how many messages sendmail has queued?

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, sendmail

sendmail 8.14.4

I want to setup monitoring to track how many queued messages I have on my sendmail server.

As per a [somewhat related linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90106/whats-the-most-resource-efficient-way-to-count-how-many-files-are-in-a-director) I understand that the most efficient way to count raw files in a directory is `\ls -afq | wc -l` but I'd like something that returns a count of messages.  Since sendmail stores queued messages in two parts (df and qf files) this can be misleading.

Comment: can't test it right now, but you want something like `mailq | grep "Total requests"`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the suggestion.  I thought about something similar but that seems like it would require a lot of administrative overhead...  because the mailq command would be generating details on error, last retry time, sender, etc -- even if it was filtered out later.

Comment: Unless your mail queue is corrupted you should have an equal number of `qf` and `df` files, so why not just count one of them?  Such as `ls -afq qf* | wc -l`

Comment: @chicks Fair enough - that's probably the easiest. If you want to submit as an answer, I'll upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your mail queue is corrupted you should have an equal number of `qf` and `df` files, so why not just count one of them? Such as:

```
ls -afq qf* | wc -l
```

Comment: **WARNING**: AFAIR older sendmail releases contained script to purge left behind garbage files from the queue directory.  It may help to periodically compare "basic count" with results reported by `mailq`.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Noted, however the concern here is that if the queue is large, the `mailq` command would consume extra system resources gathering extra information that may not be necessary for the purpose of getting a raw count.  The idea is to use this metric for a monitoring tool/dashboard.  I'll update the original post to include the version of sendmail.

Comment: And just to finish the thought here in case other folks stumble across this: the complete command might look something like: `ls -afq /var/spool/mqueue/qf* | wc -l` where `/var/spool/mqueue/` is your queue directory.  I mention this because running the command remotely wouldn't necessarily execute from the queue directory itself.